# IDL function GAUSSFIT.pro error

Tags: function, runtime-error, idl-programming-language

I'm trying to use the built-in IDL function gaussfit.pro, and every time I try, I get the following error:

```
% Keyword parameters not allowed in call. 
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$
```

I'm only trying to get the function to work right now, so I'm just running the sample code from the [gaussfit help file](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/GAUSSFIT.html), which calls the function like so:

```
yfit = GAUSSFIT(x, y, coeff, NTERMS=nterms)
```

This call doesn't even include a keyword parameter, so I'm baffled. I've also tried calling it with keywords set (e.g. NTERMS=nterms), and I get the same error.

I have IDL version 8.3.0, if that make a difference. If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering if you are getting the correct `GAUSSFIT`. Maybe you have a third party library in your `!path` that has a `GAUSSFIT` routine? Check with:

```
IDL> print, file_which('gaussfit.pro')
```

or, after attempting to call `GAUSSFIT`:

```
IDL> help, /source
```

The docs don't indicate that anything in `GAUSSFIT` has changed since IDL 8.3, so you should be OK there.

Comment: Thank you! This was essentially the problem. The copy of `GAUSSFIT` was correct, but `GAUSSFIT` itself calls `CURVEFIT`, and the copy of `CURVEFIT` that was compiling was from a third party library.

I deleted the extra `CURVEFIT` and that solved the issue.